# Could not find goal 'run' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

[ERROR] Could not find goal 'run' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.10 among available goals clean, configure-workspace, eclipse, help, install-plugins, myeclipse, myeclipse-clean, rad, rad-clean, remove-cache, resolve-workspace-dependencies, to-maven -> [Help 1]

```
    <build>
  <pluginManagement>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.7.0</version>
     <configuration>
      <!-- put your configurations here -->
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
     </configuration>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
 </build>
```

i have used above plugin. please can anyone suggest me ,what is the issue and where i am wrong .

Comment: The error is related to maven-eclipse-plugin while the snippet of code that you posted contains only maven-compiler-plugin. You should post the full log...

Comment: Never use the eclipse plugin anymore retired...

Comment: @gdegani - i am using maven-compiler-plugin. Here the error is 'Could not find goal 'run' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins' .My question is The plugin have the goal 'run' or else i need to use some other plugin.

Comment: The pom is incomplete, what you posted is just a configuration for the maven-compiler-plugin. The error says clearly that you are trying to invoke the goal "run" on maven-eclipse-plugin ( that does "not" have a run goal), it is not related to the maven-compiler-plugin. Anyway, org.apache.maven.plugins is just the groupId, not the artefactId or plugin name.

Comment: @gdegani - It is not allowing me to post all the pom file.I have added compiler plugin that you can see in my question.Is there any other way to post pom file.please let me know.Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can create a gist...